# Detect line break with css

Tags: html, css

I'd like to detect a line break with css. How can I achive this? Is it possible with css? 
so that I can set a different background color to `D`. I don't know the exact width of the elements and I don't know how many I'll have.

I have to add some space between the rows. If there are 3 rows I need space between 1 / 2 and 2 / 3.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0:
}

.abc {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.element {
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <div class="element">a</div>
  <div class="element">b</div>
  <div class="element">c</div>
  <div class="element">d</div>
  <div class="element">e</div>
</div>
```

Comment: only the D element? what if you will have more line break?

Comment: @TemaniAfif so that I can add some space between the rows. If there are 3 rows I need space between 1 / 2 and 2 / 3.

Comment: so make this clear in your question because it can be done without the need of detecting any line break

Comment: @TemaniAfif updated the question :)!

Comment: You could achieve this with nth-child. Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: @fbuchlak I don't know which nth-child it is. This depends on the width, which is unknown :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this can be done with CSS but here is a simple javascript that compare divs based on their position:

1. I define a class to all elements and add another class I called "break" that changes the background color of the first element in the next line.
2. I put my divs on HTML
3. I loop on all elements having the same class and get thru `getBoundingClientRect()` their current position. This method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.
4. I store the element in a variable I call `current` and I compare the Top position of the `current` a the `previous` element if any `previous` element.
5. I create a `previous` element as a clone of the `current` one that I will be using to compare with the following elements.

```js
var elmnt =  document.getElementsByClassName('elmnt');
var previous=null;
    for (var i = 0; i < elmnt.length; i++) {
 var current=elmnt.item(i);
 var currentRect= current.getBoundingClientRect();
 if(previous!=null) {
     var previousRect= previous.getBoundingClientRect();
    
     if(currentRect.top!=previousRect.top) {
         current.classList.add("break");
  } 
 }
 var previous=current;
    }
```

```css
.elmnt {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px; 
    background-color: green; 
    height: 100px;
    border:1px solid #333;
}

.break {
    background-color: yellow!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="elmnt">1</div>
    <div class="elmnt">2</div>
    <div class="elmnt">3</div>
    <div class="elmnt">4</div>
    <div class="elmnt">5</div>
    <div class="elmnt">6</div>
    <div class="elmnt">7</div>
    <div class="elmnt">8</div>
    <div class="elmnt">9</div>
</div>
```